# Why can't I pgrep a process?

Tags: linux, bash

```
$ ps aux | grep -i ssh
USER      4364  0.0  0.0   9004  1032 ?        Ss   12:20   0:00 ssh -v -fND localhost:4000 USERNAME@SERVER-IP-ADDRESS

$ pgrep localhost:4000
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

By default, `pgrep(1)` will only match against the process name. If you want to match against the full command line, use the `-f` option:

```
$ pgrep -f localhost:4000
```

Comment: To understand why this happens, look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/267021/249938

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at the [man page for pgrep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep). It is not just an alias for running ps with a bunch of columns and then greping the text output. It actually searches specific fields for values. By default, it only looks at the *process name* when doing a search and returns the *PID*. You can search the full command line by adding the `-f` option. You can also search several other fields that might be useful such as matching the terminal where a process is running or the group id.