# pgrep full match not work, only part, why?

Tags: ps, process-management

I use pgrep from procps-3.3.10.

If I have executable `aout_abcdefgh_ver27`,
then

```
pgrep aout_abcdefgh_ver27
```

returns nothing, while `ps aux | grep aout_abcdefgh_ver27` returns the expected result:

```
ps aux | grep aout_abcdefgh_ver27 
evgeniy  14806  0.0  0.0   4016   672 pts/8    S    12:50   0:00 ./aout_abcdefgh_ver27
evgeniy  15241  0.0  0.0  12596  2264 pts/8    S+   12:50   0:00 grep --colour=auto aout_abcdefgh_ver27
```

But if I run

```
$ pgrep aout_abcdefgh_v
14806
```

`pgrep` returns what I expect, so I wonder why it works in such a strange way, maybe I should use some option for `pgrep` to work
with full process name?

It looks like it has a very short limit for the pattern, something like ~ 10 symbols.

Comment: What is the command line you use to launch the process? Ideally, [edit] your question and show us the output of `ps aux | grep a.out`.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for comment, I update my question

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem is that by default, `pgrep` only searches the process *name*. The name is a truncated version of the entire command. You can see what the name is by looking at `/proc/PID/status` where `PID` is the process ID of the relevant process. For example:

```
$ ./aout_abcdefgh_ver27 &
[1] 14255                    ## this is the PID
$ grep Name /proc/14255/status
Name:   aout_abcdefgh_v
```

So yes, `pgrep` with no flags only reads the first 15 characters of the executable's name. To search the full command line used to launch it, you need the `-f` flag (from `man pgrep`):

```
-f, --full
     The pattern is normally only matched against the process name.  
     When -f is set, the full command line is used.
```

So, if you use `-f`:

```
$ pgrep -f aout_abcdefgh_ver27 
14255
```