# Why does pgrep not find systemd-resolved?

Tags: dns, systemd-networkd, systemd-resolved, pgrep

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "pgrep not finding systemd-resolved has bitten many times."
if [ -z $(pgrep systemd-resolved) ]; then 
  echo -e "systemd-resolved not found by pgrep, trying another way.\n"; 
  ps aux | egrep -i '(DNS|HOST|DH|RESOLV|systemd-resolved)' | egrep -v 'grep -E'; 
fi;
```

```
systemd-resolved not found by pgrep, trying another way:    
systemd+     **914**  0.0  0.0  26196  4048 ?        Ss   Nov12   0:02 /lib/systemd/**systemd-resolved**
rjt        73300  0.0  0.0   9228  2160 pts/2    S+   23:02   0:00 grep -E --color=auto -i (DNS|HOST|DH|RESOLV|systemd-resolved)
```

I work on many different systems of various age.  Need to know the backend name resolution system and what is covered by the name resolver.   So I often use pgrep to find all dns related processes.

Appears to be a string length limit for pgrep?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pgrep full match not work, only part, why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267007/pgrep-full-match-not-work-only-part-why)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [`man pgrep`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html#NOTES),

> The process name used for matching is limited to the  15  characters  present in the output of `/proc/pid/stat`.  Use the `-f` option         to match against the complete command line, `/proc/pid/cmdline`.

“systemd-resolved” has 16 characters, so it falls foul of this limit. If you run `pgrep -f systemd-resolved` you’ll find the process.