# pgrep returns correct results only for partial script name

Tags: bash, rhel, process, pgrep

I have a script called `synchronize_dirs.sh` which just wraps a call to `sleep`:

```
-bash-4.2$ cat synchronize_dirs.sh
#!/bin/bash

sleep 60
-bash-4.2$
```

What's confusing to me is the behavior of `pgrep` in the following scenario:

```
-bash-4.2$ ./synchronize_dirs.sh &
[1] 23593
-bash-4.2$ ./synchronize_dirs.sh &
[2] 23596
-bash-4.2$
-bash-4.2$ pgrep synchronize_dir
23593
23596
-bash-4.2$
-bash-4.2$ pgrep synchronize_dirs
-bash-4.2$
```

If I use the -f flag, then obviously `pgrep` does the right thing here:

```
-bash-4.2$ ./synchronize_dirs.sh &
[1] 23971
-bash-4.2$ ./synchronize_dirs.sh &
[2] 23993
-bash-4.2$
-bash-4.2$ pgrep -f synchronize_dirs
23971
23993
-bash-4.2$
```

Why does `pgrep`, with no extra flags, give the correct results only when the script name is not fully specified?

In case it's relevant, I'm running on RHEL 7.9, bash version 4.2.46, and `pgrep` version 3.3.10:

```
-bash-4.2$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)
-bash-4.2$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
-bash-4.2$ pgrep --version
pgrep from procps-ng 3.3.10
-bash-4.2$
```

Comment: You're bumping up against the 15 character limit in /proc/pid/stat I think - see [Why does pgrep not find systemd-resolved?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/725237/why-does-pgrep-not-find-systemd-resolved)